# View the contents of a database column inside the combobox

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

I would like to view the contents of a database column inside the combobox. I know it's easy, yet I can't. I'm just starting out with Python. I must have made a mess and something wrong. How can I do?

Please show me the code in the answer, both because being new to Python I might not understand, and because this way I can assign the best answer. Thanks

Updated my code

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('folder db')
cursor = con.cursor()

def combo_city():
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Table1')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result


city=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 25)
city['value'] = combo_city()
city.place(x=13, y=80)
city.set("Select")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to connect to the database then execute the required SQL statement. You should then use [`cursor.fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) or [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) or [`cursor.fetchmany(size)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany) depending on your requirement.

Here is an example.

```py
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from itertools import chain


def create_db():

    with sqlite3.connect("sample.db") as conn:
        conn.cursor().executescript("""
                            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(city VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY);
                            INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES ('Tokoyo'), ('New York');
                            """)

def load_combobox():

     with sqlite3.connect("sample.db") as conn:
        cur = conn.execute("SELECT city FROM table1")
        cities = list(chain.from_iterable(cur.fetchall()))
        combo.config(values=cities)

root = tk.Tk()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root)
combo.pack()

create_db()
load_combobox()

root.mainloop()
```

---

relevant links for you to explore [`with statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), [`executescript`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript), [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: PART 1. Thank you for answering me. Yes, I know you need to connect to the database first. I did, but I didn't paste that piece of code. I did it differently than you, without creating the function, without with, without executescript. So: db = Database ('folder db'), then con = sqlite3.connect ('folder db'), then cursor = con.cursor (). What is the difference between using the database as I wrote and as you did? The comment is too long, I continue in the next comment.

Comment: PART 2. What does it mean to use with?What does it mean to use itertools and chain?In the past I had created something similar (copying the code from the web),but I had used an easier way,not cities=list (chain.from_iterable (cur.fetchall. I have updated the code of my question (look at it), modifying it in relation to the code I am talking about. What is the difference between my code and your kind code suggested to me? Can you explain your code in detail please? I do not understand chain and the whole line cities = list (chain.from_iterable (cur.fetchall ())). Thanks

Comment: [with](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) is a context manager. In short, it helps in allocating and releasing the resources correctly. Read that link for more explanation.  The itertools comes with python as the standard library and has a lot of functions to simplify things for you, [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) is one of them that help you flatten nested lists or iterables.

Comment: `conn.executescript()` helps in executing multiple SQL statements, instead of having to writing `conn.execute()` multiple times.

Comment: Ah OK. Instead chain what is it for? And what is the difference between your code and mine of the post (my code that I have modified and updated). Can you answer me specifically please? (also Part 1, Part2). So I'll give you the best answer and close the question. Thanks

Comment: @CarryOnWaywardSon96 I don't have time currently to explain all of it, so I have included relevant links. I also suggest you take up some more python courses. Most of the time looking up the documentation should help you.

Comment: That is fine. You have been very kind. Thanks. I'll assign you as the best answer. I cannot rate your answer (arrow up) because I have recently signed up and do not have a reputation yet.